# Getting Insights around PostgreSQL Cursor from Audit Logs : CloudSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-logging, cursors

I have mostly this audit log everywhere in my cloud logging console from cloudsql postgresql audit logs.

```
{
  "textPayload": "2023-04-27 08:03:17.058 UTC [980077]: [41406-1] db=xyz,user=xyz LOG:  duration: 6166.869 ms  statement: FETCH 10000 FROM c1",
  "insertId": "s=4ae93d4dfabf4fc6b09ckdanknc0f18e2;i=39eexcb;b=eca5cad5acb84ckjndkj9e5a3af5dc7aee47;m=153c87ckac099b;t=5fa4cca00kjbad2ae;x=aa1f7345cca3ckbcjb81d-0-0@a1",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloudsql_database",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "xyz",
      "database_id": "xyz:postgres",
      "region": "europe-west9"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-04-27T08:03:17.059246Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "INSTANCE_UID": "12-d77d8db7-0633-4695-b4c7-0a8cdhdknec9392",
    "LOG_BUCKET_NUM": "38"
  },
  "logName": "projects/xyz/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fpostgres.log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-04-30T08:03:20.820646796Z"
}
```

I tried querying `pg_cursors` but since there is no active connection, I didn't see any data.

I would like to trace the original query behind this cursor `c1` or get more details around this `FETCH 10000 FROM c1` query.

How can i get more details by using cloud logging or querying postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

The **statement: FETCH 10000 FROM C1** which is showing in the log you mentioned is the original(backend) query which was executed in postgresql. This query will retrieve the next 10000 rows from the cursor **C1** because without any direction by default the postgresql considers **direction as NEXT**.

Refer this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) for more detailed inforatmion about FETCH command.

If you want to know more detailed information about this **PgAudit** log then try executing this query by changing the **logName** as your **logName (logName: "projects/xyz/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fpostgres.log")**

```
resource.type="cloudsql_database"
logName="projects/<your-project-name>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
protoPayload.request.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.audit.v1.PgAuditEntry"
```

The output will be something like this

```
{
  protoPayload: {
    @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
    methodName: "cloudsql.instances.query"
    request: {
      @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.audit.v1.PgAuditEntry"
      auditClass: "READ"
      auditType: "SESSION"
      chunkCount: "1"
      chunkIndex: "1"
      command: "SELECT"
      database: "finance"
      databaseSessionId: 2209692
      parameter: "[not logged]"
      statement: "SELECT * FROM C1"
      statementId: 2
      substatementId: 1
      user: "alice"
    }
  }
}
```

Here the **statement value refers to the query executed on the backend**. This query will help to get more detailed information about the **Audit Logs**. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit#viewing-audit-logs) for more information about the query and audit logs.

**Updated:**

Database auditing in Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is available through the open-source **pgAudit extension**. By using this extension, you can selectively record and track SQL operations performed against a given database instance.
The extension provides you with auditing capabilities to monitor and record a select subset of operations.

The **pgAudit extension** applies to executed SQL commands and queries. In contrast, Cloud Audit Logs should be used to audit administrative and maintenance operations done on a Cloud SQL instance.

Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions) to Configure the PostgreSQL pgAudit extension.

Comment: I don't see any data in my case for this filter `protoPayload.request.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.audit.v1.PgAuditEntry"`

Comment: Hi @SRJ I updated the answer with more detailed information. Try adding the extension as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks and i do have pgaudit enabled already

Comment: Hi @SRJ may I know what the exact query you executed?  Can you try executing the query mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit#viewing-audit-logs) , just change the <your-project-name> to yours.

Comment: I didn't execute the query, I am trying to find the original query behind the FETCH query being executed which I saw in audit logs.